# how to use api key while accessing google sheets using android

Tags: android, oauth, google-sheets-api, api-key

we are accessing google sheets using OAuth, but we require that "user consent"(ask for google sign in) should not be asked, because we assume the user does not have a gmail id. Can anyone guide us on how to embed API Key with our request to access google sheets ?

Comment: Unless you mark the sheet as "Anyone with Link can view" you will be prompted.

Comment: @jwilleke  we changed the sheet sharing permission to "Anyone with link can view", but it still asks for user consent.